# Faster way to take snapshots ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uigraphicscontext, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I have a `UICollectionView`. I want to generate two snapshots for each objects.

Sample Code:

```
        for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {

            UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            dummyView.frame = some frame....,
            dummyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(dummyView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
            [dummyView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            NSData *imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(outputImage, 1.00f);
            //Write file.
        }
```

I have written the code in cellForItemAtIndexPath. If there is no image in the path, it will create automatically. So when I launch the application for the first time, the UI is not responsive since there are many snapshots are getting created. This slow down the user interaction. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: I think cellfor row at indexpath is not the right place to call. That method will get called many times, results in more screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Use `drawViewHierarchyInRect` instead of `drawInContext` as it's much faster

See the iOS 7 example here: https://coderwall.com/p/56wcfq/fast-snapshot-any-views-on-ios-7